# Can I sign up for Wework as a tourist?

Tags: uk, work

I’m traveling to the UK soon and would need some office space for effective remote work. Could I sign up for WeWork as a tourist or do I have to be a resident?

Comment: WeWork seems to be a global company with locations in dozens of countries. I don't see anything about needing to be a resident anywhere. Was there a specific problem that you encountered when trying to book some space with WeWork in the UK?

Comment: @GregHewgill you need to show up at their front desk with ID to get your access card. I don’t want to be told “sorry you’re a tourist” when I arrive. I’ve tried to email them but didn’t get a response.

Comment: I don't see what the problem actually is here. This seems pretty obviously clear to me: https://help.wework.com/s/article/How-do-I-register-my-keycard. Perhaps they don't answer questions that have already been answered by their published FAQ.

Comment: Surely a question for the company itself

Comment: @Midavalo or other Wework customers, who may also happen to use this site

Comment: as a tourist (as in "tourist visa"), you're not allowed to work

Comment: @njzk2 it's allowed if working isn't the primary purpose of the trip: https://www.carterthomas.co.uk/can-visitors-to-the-uk-work-remotely/

Comment: Some remote working while in the UK as a visitor is allowed if the visitor is undertaking limited activities relating to their employment overseas (eg isn’t self-employed), and remote working isn’t the primary purpose of the trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in Australia, I can confirm that they do not care about your visa status. They do not ask for a passport, my European id card was good enough to simply verify my identity. They're not in the business of enforcing the government's visa policies. This could of course vary by country and local laws, but I doubt it's different in the UK.

If in doubt you could sign up in your home country and pick up a card there, which should be usable in all their locations worldwide and just require an online reservation without further in-person interaction.